# How to resolve this Syntax error

Tags: verilog

Am trying to code a top level module that would connect different modules to make an up/down counter that would display a hexadecimal character on a 7 segment LED on posedges; but every time I try to run the following top level module I get an error that says

'Line 25: Syntax error near "<=".'

There is no one else to ask this and am following the same outline of the example in my reference book. What am I doing wrong?

```
module Main_Module(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, U, R, P, Clk);
   input U, R, P, Clk;
   output a, b, c, d, e, f, g;
   reg [3:0] Data;
   wire In3 <= Data[3], In2 <= Data[2], In1 <= Data[1], In0 <= Data[0];  //This is Line 25

  Counter Counter_1(Clk_1Hz, R, P, U, Data);
  Segment_Display Segment_Display_1(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, In3, In2, In1, In0);
  ClkDiv1Hz ClkDiv1Hz_1(Clk, R, Clk_1Hz);

endmodule
```

Thank you Eugene Sh.and Greg  for your time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wires need blocking assignments (`=`), not non-blocking (`<=`). You can define it this way:

```
wire In3 = Data[3], In2 = Data[2], In1 = Data[1], In0 = Data[0];
```

Example [here](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/URY)

More commonly you will see the declaration and assignments as separate statements. The two are functionally equivalent

```
wire In3, In2, In1, In0;
assign {In3, In2, In1, In0} = Data;
```

Comment: That Works! I always had this problem with assignments, though could get away with "<=" in all assignments I need. Do you know if that would effect flow of bits? Because I was told that non-blocking assignments are instant while the blocking assignments are slower

Comment: Non-blocking is not slower, just updated in a later region in the scheduler. This is to prevent race conditions for flop to flop assignments. Generally flops (latches edge triggered flip-flops) should be assigned with non-blocking assignments, everything else should be blocking assignments.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to declare and use the non-blocking assignment to a wire in the same line. Verilog does not allow using non-blocking assignments in this way. Either use the blocking assignment `=` or first declare the wires:

```
wire In3;
wire In2;
wire In1;
wire In0;
```

and then assign them somewhere:

```
In3 <= Data[3];
In2 <= Data[2];
..............
```

or even better:

```
wire [3:0] In;
......
In <= Data; // Assuming your data is 4 bit
```

Comment: I tried the first way you suggested and I got few errors that said "In3 is an unknown type" "In2 is an unknown type""In1 is an unknown type" and "In0 is an unknown type" even though  I already declared them as wires

Comment: I couldn't use the easier method because the module "Segment_Display" have In3, In2, In1 and In0 rather that [3:0] In

Comment: If you show the complete code, we will resolve it as well.

Comment: @user3465945 You can pass `In[0], In[1],...` to the module.

Comment: The complete code will fill the entire screen, should I change the "Segment_Display" ports so I can use the easy way you put?

Comment: @user3465945 If you have an access to the module declaration, the answer is yes. Bus notation for a related signals is much more readable and preferable than distinct wires, especially with the same name.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Wires can be declared and assigned in the same line. Multiple declarations & assignments is the same line are also allowed. They cannot be assigned with non-blocking assignments.